# How to calculate the difference between two java.sql.Time values?

Tags: java, mysql

i have table like below,

```
id | Lunch_Out | After_Lunch_In

01   |  01:15:00   |   02:00:01
```

I am trying to find time difference using below code,

```
while(rst.next())
            {
                PrintWriter obj1 = response.getWriter();
                obj1.println("while entered");

                Time a =rst.getTime("Lunch_Out");
                Time b =rst.getTime("After_Lunch_In");

                PrintWriter objt1 = response.getWriter();
                objt1.println("LougOut Time is :"+b);
                PrintWriter objt2 = response.getWriter();
                objt2.println("LogIn Time is :"+a);

//long c = b.getTime() - a.getTime() 

                long c = b.getTime() - a.getTime() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                //PrintWriter objtr = response.getWriter();
                //objtr.println("different  is :"+c);

                Time diff = new Time(c);

                PrintWriter objt = response.getWriter();
                objt.println("different  is :"+diff);

            }
```

**Output is:**

```
while entered

LougOut Time is :02:00:02

LogIn Time is :01:15:01

different  is :02:00:02
```

But expecting output is : **00:45:01**.where i am doing mistake?

Comment: I think your operator precedence is messed up.  Don't you want to subtract the times, then scale the difference?

Comment: @OldProgrammer sorry cant get u!

Comment: I suggest you let MySQL do the math for you as part of your query, something like `SELECT Lunch_Out, After_Lunch_In, subtime(After_Lunch_In, Lunch_Out) as Lunch_Duration FROM ...`.  See the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) for details.

Comment: For DateComparisons, have a look into JodaTime. It makes data/time calculations really easy...

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If you're using Java 8 you won't have to use JodaTime for easy calculations.

Comment: @Paul i m using java7

Comment: Use brackets around your subtraction

Comment: @CocoNess even i tried that but result is,"different  is :05:30:00"

Comment: Use Calendar class in Java7

Comment: As @CodeNewbie stated in his answer, you don't have to divide, the constructor of the `Time` class takes milliseconds.

Comment: @OldProgrammer is right in my opinion. Java operator precedence takes into account adding and substraction AFTER multiplication and division. Try : `long c = (b.getTime() - a.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: @sashok_bg No.if i do your update my c value is=0 and diff is=05:30:00.why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are converting both `a` and `b` to milliseconds (since epoch) then getting the difference. Since your subsequent line involves invoking the [Time constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#Time(long)), you don't need to scale the time to days by dividing with 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 as you have done. Take the `c` value only as a difference in milliseconds, then convert it into the Time object `diff` in the next line.

Your updated code should look like this.

```
long c = b.getTime() - a.getTime();
Time diff = new Time(c);
```

However, this will give you a Time object with the correct number of hours, minutes and seconds but whose date will be January 1, 1970. As you have added the MySQL tag to your question, I would suggest you consider [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185034/paul)'s suggestion in his comment.

> I suggest you let MySQL do the math for you as part of your query, something like SELECT Lunch_Out, After_Lunch_In, subtime(After_Lunch_In, Lunch_Out) as Lunch_Duration FROM .... See the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) for details.

Comment: No.when do your update code then i am getting result "different  is :06:15:01".

Comment: But @paul's select query working fine.but i am trying know the reason why i cant get result through my coding?

Comment: I can't think what would cause such an issue. How are the date fields stored in your table (datatype and the date format)?

Comment: I think that the 06:15:01 is the timezone (+06) offset. Because Time is converting to the Epoch Date.

Comment: The OP should be using Joda time or Java 8 time utils or Calendar. Doing it this way is the reason why the other libraries were invented :)

Comment: @CocoNess is right! I guess manivasagam is from India, which would mean that the time offset is GMT+5:30. The extra 5:30 hours added to your actual difference leads to the incorrect output.

Comment: OK, so whatever answer you get, subtract your timezone offset. How's that for a hack?

Comment: My advice to the OP: Now that we have figured out what is wrong with your code and how to get an (almost) correct value, consider doing the time manipulation in MySQL, or just use the JodaTime libraries moving forward.