# Get time difference java.sql.Time

Tags: java, sql, time

I'm trying to get the time differente between two Time vars like this

```
long timeDiffLong = hFim.getTime() - hInic.getTime();
Time timeDiff = new Time(timeDiffLong);
```

The output is comming something like this

```
hFim = 17:30:00
hInic = 17:00:00
timeDiff = 20:30:00
```

instead of just showing 00:30:00 i always get 20h plus the result

Comment: What's the value of `timeDiffLong` in this case, and how are you constructing `hFim` and `hInic`? A [mcve] here would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two java.sql.Time values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847798/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-java-sql-time-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Java 8, you can do:

```
LocalTime from = hFim.toLocalTime();
LocalTime to = hInic.toLocalTime();

Duration d = Duration.between(from, to);
```

You can then query the hour/minute etc. with e.g. `d.toMinutes()`.

Answer (score 2):

By doing this

```
 Time timeDiff = new Time(timeDiffLong);
```

you create a new time object, with `timeDiffLong` being the milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC. Since the difference is 30 minutes, the `Time` object will refer to 1970-01-01 00:30 UTC. But here comes the catch: `timeDiff.toString()` will output the time in the default time zone, that is, in most cases the time zone where you are currently are.

Long story short: Do not force an interval (duration, time difference) into a `Time` object. Either use a `Duration` class (Joda has one) or just do the division and modulo calculations yourself, as proposed by Kushan.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicated question, have you seen already this answer?

[How to find difference between two Joda-Time DateTimes in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes)

You should take a look at Joda time:

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: It is better to use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: All depends on how you see it, like everything in Life.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you create the time diff with

```
Time timeDiff = new Time(timeDiffLong);
```

and output that with `System.out.println(timeDiff)` then the result is shown *for your local time zone*. You can see that when you do this:

```
System.out.println(new Time(0));
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println(new Time(0));
```

That produces the following output here

```
00:00:00 //will probably be 20:00:00 for you
16:00:00
```

In short: Your time difference is shown as a GMT date converted to your local time zone and that is why its several hours off.